# Is there a way to minify css without it all being on one line?

Tags: css, sublimetext2, sublimetext, minify, min

I'm using Sublime Text Editor 2, and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to make it so that minified css files aren't on all one line. Any insight? Thanks!

Comment: That's what [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) is... When you minify something you remove all the unnecessary whitespace. By adding line breaks, you are by definition un-minifying your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) by definition is removing all of the unnecessary white space in your code. By adding line breaks you are doing just the opposite of that, so to answer your question: No, there is no way to have minified code that isn't all on one line.

That being said, you can use line wrap, aka word wrap, features of a text editor to remove the horizontal scrolling, but your code will still be on one line technically.

Comment: Ah yes, that's what I mean. I don't want line breaks, I'd rather just not have to scroll horizontally for five days. Any recommendations for line/word wrapping?

Comment: @alliefayden word wrap should be on by default, if it isn't, look for the "word_wrap" setting in Default File Preferences

Answer (score 1):

No. You shouldn't be trying to read/edit minified versions of CSS/JS files. Instead, you should operate on the un-minified version while in development, and use a script which minifies your CSS files (using something like YUI Compressor) when deploying to production.

> http://yui.github.io/yuicompressor/